# React Native - How to pass data to component that's an attribute inside another component

Tags: react-native, jsx

So I have this code that iterates over a list of data. I'm trying to render the avatar image, but it's not working. I'm assuming I have to somehow get "item.icon" into "props" for Avatar.Image and I'm not super sure how to do this.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {FlatList, View, Text, StyleSheet, SafeAreaView} from 'react-native';
import {Avatar, IconButton, Card, Title} from 'react-native-paper';
import Loader from '../components/Loader';

return (
<SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
<FlatList
style={styles.flatlist}
data={[
          {
icon: 'https://www.google.com/url?sa=i&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.flaticon.com%2Ffree-icon%2Favatar_194938&psig=AOvVaw3_3HQARQJzjX8MBiBqsmxM&ust=1627701465958000&source=images&cd=vfe&ved=0CAsQjRxqFwoTCJCz6c_qifICFQAAAAAdAAAAABAD',
username: 'John Smith',
date: 'June 20 2021',
          },
        ]}
renderItem={({item}) => (
<Card mode={'outlined'} style={{marginBottom: 10}}>
<Card.Title
title={item.username}
subtitle={item.date}
icon={item.icon}
left={props => (
<Avatar.Image size={35} source={{uri: item.icon}} />
              )}
/>
</Card>
        )}
/>
</SafeAreaView>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue is with your image url, better use a direct link to your image, like this https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/194/194938.png